# How to compile java code on command prompt after installing java and setting environment variables?

Tags: java, cmd

I have written a java code, it is inside the java programs folder on my desktop.
How can I compile and run it ?

Comment: The program you want is `javac`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open command prompt
2. Go to your java programs folder i.e. type `cd java programs`
3. Compile your code i.e. type `javac YOUR_JAVA_PROGRAM_NAME.java`
4. Above command generates a java class file which is your executable file, to run it type `java YOUR_PROGRAM_NAME`